# Add and Register Service Provider with adding new Role and Permission In WSO2is using Java

Tags: java, wsdl, wso2-identity-server

I am new to using WSO2 Identity Server and currently using 5.2.0 version of WSO2is. I have a requirement to add Custom Role and Permission into Tenant that is configured with LDAP Using UserStore.

I am following the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS550/Adding+and+Configuring+a+Service+Provider) and through wso2is created, but I want to create tenant-based dynamically using java code.

Here I am not able to find any java code or WSDL file related to Service Provider or what is the procedure to add/register Service Provider from java code.

Please, help what should I do to create Service Provider with Role and Permission from java code.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the ApplicationManagementService to create applications dynamically by invoking the createApplication() method. Sample requests are defined in [1].

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS520/Using+the+Service+Provider+API

Comment: Thanks, @sathya this is the perfect reference.